# Djang multiple levels of template extension while keeping the elements of the upper levels

Tags: django, django-templates

I have 3 templates as following:
`base.html` (the top level template, as usual).

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
```

`category.html` :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    
      <div class="category_row">
        <div id="menu_category_display">
          {% for category in menu_categories %}
            {% with category_button="menu_"|add:category.name|lower %}
                <button class="button category_buttons {{category_button}}"
                        onclick="showItem('{{category_button}}','category_buttons')">
                    {{category}}
                </button>
            {% endwith %}
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item_row">
        {% block level_2_content %}
        {% endblock %}

      </div>
         

{% endblock %}
```

and `item.htlm`

```
{% extends "menu/category.html" %}

{% block level_2_content %}
<div id="test_div">
    {% for item in menu_items %}
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

When `item.html` is rendered, all the elements that were rendered by `category.html` are gone. Only the elements of the `base.html` are retained.

How do I retain all elements in all parent templates instead of just `base.html`? A general method to do this for more than 3 levels of extension like in my case?

Update with more detailed code for `category.html`. The entire `category_row` div does not appear in `item.html`. How do I retain them?

`views.py`

```
def menu_category_view(request, table_pk):
    menu_categories = Category.objects.all()
    menu_items = Item.objects.filter(available=True)
    return render(request,
                  'menu/category.html',
                  {'menu_categories': menu_categories,
                   'menu_items': menu_items,
                   'table_pk': table_pk})


def menu_item_view(request, menu_category, table_pk):
    category = Category.objects.get(name=menu_category)
    menu_items = Item.objects.filter(available=True,
                                     category=category.pk)

    return render(request,
                  'menu/item.html',
                  {'menu_items': menu_items})
```

Folder structure: both templates sit in `menu/templates/menu` of app `menu`. However, `base.html` sits in `root/templates` (not in app `menu`.

Update: I have tried modifying both templates in various ways to debug. What I find is that the static content gets extended, but the dynamic content does not. So my question becomes: ***does Django template allow dynamic content to be extended to child / grandchild templates?***

Comment: can you show us the `templates` folder structure ?

Comment: @cizario Please see my update above. Thanks.

Comment: i guess `{% extends "category/category.html" %}` should be `{% extends "menu/category.html" %}`

Comment: @cizario That was a copy-paste mistake. It is correct in my original code. Updated my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use "extends" here but instead ["include"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include) to render 'item.html' within the parent document.